# How to get response headers for 303 request using Axios reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, browser, axios

I am using below code

```
    const configureAjaxClient = () => {
        let csrf_token = '';
        const instance = axios.create({
            baseURL: '/abc',
            timeout: 300000,
            paramsSerializer: (params) => {
                return qs.stringify(params, { arrayFormat: 'brackets' });
            },
        });

        instance.interceptors.request.use((config) => {
            config.headers['X-CSRF-Token'] = csrf_token;
            if (config.data) {
                config.data = qs.stringify(config.data);
            }
            return config;
        });

        instance.interceptors.response.use((response) => {
            if (response.data) {
                return Promise.reject(response);
            }
            return response;
        }, (error) => {
            return Promise.reject(error);
        });

        return instance;
    };

    export default configureAjaxClient;
```

when my request is 303 is redirect to location header in response, and error function is called with below

```
    errorError:Network  Error
        at createError (createError.js:16)
        at XMLHttpRequest.handleError (xhr.js:87)
```

And in error I get error.response as undefined.

How will I get response headers, and I want the redirect to another route.

Please help
I am using latest Axios and reactjs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This header was missing in the request which my server is checking that its Ajax request or not

```
// Headers
// This header is required to inform server that its an Ajax request
instance.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'] = 'XMLHttpRequest';
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't. Axios is a wrapper around XMLHttpRequest which handles redirect responses transparently and has no option to change that.

If you were to switch to fetch, then you could use [a request object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Request/Request) to specify that redirections were not followed automatically.

Comment: But why I am getting error.reponse as undefined
at least I should get response header which I am able to see in Network tab.

Answer (score 0):

As of right now, you can:

```js
    const response = axios('your303endpoint')
      .catch(data => data.response.headers)
      .then(headers => console.log(headers))
```